# How to interact with service worker notifications with actions?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, service-worker

How do I simulate with `selenium-webdriver` the clicking of a specific action of a [notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification) launched from a service worker that include `actions` in its `options` parameter?

I know I can use javascript to [look up which notifications are active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/getNotifications), and I can even see [which actions are present](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification/actions) in the notification.

I can also [close the notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/close) and that will send an `onnotificationclose` event to the service worker, but not the [`onnotificationclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/onnotificationclick) event and certainly not with a `.action` information of which action was chosen by the user.

So, how do I test interactions with notifications using `selenium-webdriver`? (specifically, the Python version)

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: @JeffC my point is exactly that I couldn't find a way of doing what I'm asking, so there is no source code to show.